# Switching function from MYSQL to MYSQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm currently switching from mysql to mysqli and I'm getting errors when I'm converting this function which was working under mysql.

```
include("config.php");
function getUsername($uid){
    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id='".$uid."' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error(""));
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $row['username'];
}
```

Errors:

> Notice: Undefined variable: conn
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
> in
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given
> in

How should it be written?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notice: Undefined variable: conn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699994/notice-undefined-variable-conn)

Comment: You have a history of low-research and regularily downvoted questions and might lose your question-asking privileges. [You should read this before you post your next one.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/before-you-post-your-next-question)

Answer (score -1):

Problem Solved.

Added

```
global $conn;
```

inside the function.